# R loop from a txt or csv file

Tags: r, loops

I am learning to use R and I am working with the `for` loop

Here is an example:

```
for (loopvalues in c(1,5,8,10,19)){

  print(paste("The number is", loopvalues))

}
```

I was wondering what can be done if the list of values is as big as 100 or 1000 different values and they follow no patterns.

I imagined I can have the values saved in a csv or a txt file beforehand, but how could I tell the loop command to read the values from that file?

I am sure the question is very basic, so I thank you beforehand for your help!

Comment: Start by taking a look at `read.csv`.

Comment: Hi Imo, thanks for the advice, I will start looking for some tutorials on read csv. and for loops!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For loops can be used for extremely long lists however you will often find that they become slow and you will want to use other commands such as the `apply` family.

You do not have to name all the values in the loop. One way to accomplish this is using the `in`. Here is an example using the mtcars data set that is preloaded into R.

```
    for(c in unique(mtcars$carb)){

      print(c)

    }
```

By using the `unique` function, I don't even have to know what all the possible values of `mtcars$carb` are but I can still loop through them.

Additionally, you probably want to practice your googling skills instead of asking StackOverflow. Most of the questions you're going to ask when learning R are already out there.

Comment: Hi Svenhalvorson! thank you very much for your answer, I will make a more detailed look for these kind of basic questions, thanks once again!